# Como fazer uma tabela que só aceite número de 1 a 100?

Tags: javascript, validação

Iniciei agora na programação e estou com problema. Eu estou tentando fazer uma tabela que só aceite números de 1 a 100, mas esta dando erros

```js
var num = document.getElementById("caixaNum")
var tab = document.getElementById("tab")
var res = document.getElementById("res")

function clique() {
  if (Number(num) >= 1 && Number(num) <= 100) {
    window.alert('ok')
  } else {
    window.alert('error')
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Numeros</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <div> <strong>Numeros Para Tab (entre 1 - 100):</strong>
    <input type="number" name="caixa" id="caixaNum"><input type="button" value="numeros" onclick="clique()">
    <br><br>
    <select name="tabnu" id="tab"></select> <br><br>
    <input id='fina' type="button" value="Finalizar">
  </div>
  <div id='res'></div>
</section>


<footer>
  <p>&copy;CursoemVideo</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Você está passando um elemento para a função `Number`. O correto é passar apenas o valor: `Number(num.value)`.

Comment: não , da erro tbm, acho que é no html

Comment: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/YzGYVLb

Comment: n tá indo tá dando erro no input, mas vi q o seu codigo esta certo . deve ser algo nas configurações do meu pc, vlw msm assim

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: clique is not defined ta dando isso no depois do clique

Comment: Isso quer dizer que você precisa implementar a função `clique`. Poste seu código no pastebin

Answer (score 0):

acredito que seu erro foi no operador de &&(E) ao invés de ||(OU). Fiz um exemplo prático para lhe mostrar melhor.

Eu separei os arquivos então os elementos estão em um arquivo **html** e o **JS** está em outro arquivo que eu importei como pode ver no `<script src="./index.js"></script>`.

HTML

```
<header>
      <h1>Número</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <!-- Um formulário com atributo "novalidate" para o formulário não se dar submit automaticamente -->
      <form id="calculo" novalidate>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="numberId"
          placeholder="Coloque um número entre 1 e 100."
        />
        <button type="submit">Verificar</button>
      </form>
    </main>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Arquivo JS onde a mágica rola, aqui eu peguei os ids dos elementos e atribui a uma constante com o mesmo nome para facilitar e então quando você clicar no botão "verificar" ele irá executar está função.

```
// Pegand o id dos elementos
const calculo = document.getElementById("calculo");
const numberId = document.getElementById("numberId");

// Uma função de submit para validar se o número é menor que 1 ou maior que 100
calculo.onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (numberId.value < 1 || numberId.value > 100) {
    alert("Número invalido!");
    // Se o número não corresponder com o valor posto ele retorna false
    return false;
  }

  // Depois do número validado ele limpa o value do input
  numberId.value = "";
};
```

Coloquei o código aqui para que você possa ver em tempo real ele executando, só basta clicar em **executar**.

```js
// Pegand o id dos elementos
const calculo = document.getElementById("calculo");
const numberId = document.getElementById("numberId");

// Uma função de submit para validar se o número é menor que 1 ou maior que 100
calculo.onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (numberId.value < 1 || numberId.value > 100) {
    alert("Número invalido!");
    // Se o número não corresponder com o valor posto ele retorna false
    return false;
  }

  // Depois do número validado ele limpa o value do input
  numberId.value = "";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Número</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Número</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <!-- Um formulário com atributo "novalidate" para o formulário não se dar submit automaticamente -->
      <form id="calculo" novalidate>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="numberId"
          placeholder="Coloque um número entre 1 e 100."
        />
        <button type="submit">Verificar</button>
      </form>
    </main>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: o input tipo number retorna um string ?? por isso temos q usa number?

Comment: Como se tratava de um input que pegasse **número** de 1 a 100 então eu pré-defini o input com `type="number"`, pois assim ele só aceitará número e não string.
  Se preferir você pode mudar o input para aceitar String, Number, Date e etc..
  Neste link que irá para a MDN mostra os types que o input aceita: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

@VitorSantos

Answer (score -1):

Como alternativa ao invés de usar um alerta para o usuário, acredito que a melhor solução, inclusive para o design, seria bloquear essa função.

Você pode utilizar as propriedades 'min' e 'max' do input type number. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<input type='number' id='quantity' name='quantity' min='1' max='5'>
```

Depois de uma olhada na documentação da Mozilla lá mostra todas as propriedades de todas as tags HTML, sempre vejo se tem algo lá antes de fazer as funções em JS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number